# Need to remove multiple entity objects when using Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework

I am new in Entity Framework. I want to remove multiple entities in one database context. If I used DBContext.Remove(Object) then It delete only the one entity from database. Please consider my code:

```
            CCSRequest objCCSRequest = DBContext.CCSRequest.Find(ccsRequestId);
            if (objCCSRequest != null)
            {
                DBContext.CCSRequest.Remove(objCCSRequest);
                DBContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            CCProducts objCCProducts = DBContext.CCProducts.Find(ccsRequestId);
            if (objCCProducts != null)
            {                    
                DBContext.CCProducts.Remove(objCCProducts);
                DBContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

I want to remove entity in both CCSRequest and CCProducts table.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a loop that will remove entities of different types you might use this:

```
object[] entities = new object[]{
    DBContext.CCSRequest.Find(ccsRequestId),
    DBContext.CCProducts.Find(ccsRequestId)
};
foreach(object entity in entities)
{
    DBContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to remove entities with different types not a same type. The problem is when I use EntityState.Deleted the i found some error like "The name EntityState" does not exist in the current context". I am using Entity Framework 4.0. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Because you need to use proper namespace for that!!! Shame on you for not resolving such a problem yourself.

Comment: Sorry for wrong question I was searching in System.Data.Entity namespace and replied you quickly. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. We are here not for providing whole ready-to-use code but instead to help solve some problems. When you ask question you should as well show some effort :)

Comment: Really Thanks for you nice assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Going by the answer to a similar question, you will need to do this in a loop. Please check the answer to this question:

[how to delete multiple rows of data with linq to EF using DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214173/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-of-data-with-linq-to-ef-using-dbcontext)